# Write a featherlight function with different filters shorter

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I'm using featherlight lightbox in a project. Now everything works but I guess there are much better and shorter ways to write my code.
Featherlight can find different images for different galleries with a filter. For 2 galleries on one page you need for each a different filter, so you can loop through the images with the specific filter. the filter should be added to the anchor.

To give the anchors the unique class I use:

```
$('.gal1').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image1' );
$('.gal2').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image2' );
$('.gal3').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-image3' );
$('.gal4').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass.....and so on.
```

The classes .gal1, gal2 or gal2 are added manualy by the conent-editor to define witch image is in witch gallery, becouse there is no direct manipulation of the anchor.

Ao what it should look like is:

```
$('.galX').find( 'a[href]' ).addClass( 'featured-imageX' );
```

and the X shoould be the same number.

My question: Is ther a shorter way to do the loop through? If not I've to write many lines till p.e 20.

My second question is quite similar:

I've called each featherlight gallery like this:

```
$('#content').each(function(_i, gallery) {       
$(gallery).featherlightGallery({
    variant: 'gal',
  filter: '.featured-image1'
});
});
$('#content').each(function(_i, gallery) {       
$(gallery).featherlightGallery({
    variant: 'gal',
  filter: '.featured-image2'
});
});
.....and so on with .featured-image3, .featured-image4...
```

There should be a better way to write this.

Maye it is possible like this:

```
$('#content').each(function(_i, gallery) {       
$(gallery).featherlightGallery({
    variant: 'gal',
  filterX: '.featured-imageX' 
});
});
```

and X should be the same number.
I hope you understand what i mean.
THX

Comment: _"Now everything works but I guess there are much better and shorter ways to write my code"_ - That's (more or less) the reason why https://codereview.stackexchange.com exists

Comment: Please, one question per post.